# Online Back up for SFX

Tags: backups

Hi

I am looking for an online backup solution for my SFX Library and computer. I am considering IDrive as you can select the folders you want to backup and the retrieval process is easy.
But are there any other solutions that I have missed?
I have backup drives in 2 locations but I want the piece of mind in having another totally 'offsite' backup.
Any advice is welcome!
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

How much data are you talking about?  Online backup is slow and can get expensive fast.  I don't use online backup for my SFX Library, because it is just too damn big.  Instead I back up to hard drives and have 2 offsite backups (at 2 different locations).

I do backup my current work online.  I've tried a few services and currently use Dropbox.  I found iDisk to be slower and more expensive than Dropbox.  Amazon S3 is the cheapest solution, but since there is no cap on the amount of data that you can store there, I wasn't managing my data very well and was getting hit with rather large monthly bills.

With Dropbox I have 200 gigs (I pay annually for that).  The assets for my current projects (PT Sessions and audio files, docs, reference material, ect) are kept in my Dropbox folder and are automatically (and constantly) syncing.  Since I have a 200 gig cap, I have to manage my data as Dropbox starts to fill up.  This means that I need to archive old projects and clean up unused audio from completed PT Sessions.

200 gigs works well for me.  I may only run into issues if I have multiple projects running at once, which very rarely happens.  I'm usually able to finish a project and archive the stuff to offsite drives before I get too deep into the next one.  I could also add more Dropbox storage if I needed too.

One thing to keep in mind, is that if you are syncing large amounts of data, the initial sync will take many days.

Comment: Hi Chuck. Thanks for that reply. At the moment it's not a huge amount of data, but I can see it getting more and more as time goes by. I'm moving towards the idea of more HD storage on physical drives in a couple of locations, and still backing up to DVD's etc! The cost of a 500GB drive is so much cheaper than the same amount of online storage! In fact I could probably buy 4 500GB drives for the cost of 1 year 500GB online storage.
I think i'm going the local storage for now!!

Answer (score 2):

For those suggesting Amazon S3 I worked through the initial & monthly costs of it:
http://www.musicofsound.co.nz/blog/a-cloud-based-fx-library-possible

Comment: Hi Tim.
Thats exactly what I wanted regarding Amazon S3, i've never been too hot at maths and the Amazon S3 info made my eyes glaze over!
Cheers for working that out and convincing me that having multiple drives in different locations is the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox is a good choice, only 2gb storage. You can pay for more though.

Other than that, if you haven't already buy some webspace and upload all your library via FTP for safe storage. Then upload new files when you have them.

Also if you have a Hotmail account you should have a "Skydrive", basically on-line storage where you get an impressive 250gb limit.

Comment: Hi Adrian
Thanks for the reply. I use DB but i'm looking for a better solution and more space. I have webspace but it's not enough to use as serious FTP storage. The SkyDrive looks interesting but for 2 reasons I don't want to sign up for that. 1. It seems too 'sharing' orientated and 2. I'm not signing up for another email address (I have too many anyway!!)

Answer (score 1):

There are also things like backblaze / mozy.
Or maybe just setup a remote NAS at a friends house?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3? Been wanting to start using it for storage... But haven't yet taken the plunge. I also haven't done the calculations to see how much it would actually cost.

Comment: Ah, yes. I hadn't considered that but it's worth a look! Thanks.

Comment: Looked into Amazon S3 and it's way to complicated and could end up being too expensive. I think it's more designed for corporate use or at least for people with extensive IT skills. Way too confusing for me!!

Comment: take a look at the Jungledisk for S3. Simple to use and great for scheduled OR constant backups.

Comment: I number crunched Amazon S3 for my library:
http://www.musicofsound.co.nz/blog/a-cloud-based-fx-library-possible

Comment: @tim i guess there comes a point at which you can just buy a new hard drive every month and store it off-site! but, if you were using AWS for backup only, you'd obviously compress the data to save storage and bandwidth cost. (at this point the religious audiofiles jump in and try and persuade us that the think audio from some hardrives sound different or they can hear when uncompressed audio has been zipped and unzipped!)

Answer (score 0):

as IT Manager in a leader industry, I can suggest you to buy a reliable RAID 1 external disk. In this way, all data are mirrored on two drives. Do a backup at least once a week and, for more security, once a month do a backup on another drive. Use online solution only for critical files.

Comment: if the building burns down you're stuffed no matter how many drives you mirror or sync to. off-site backup is essential.

Comment: I assumed he's not a company but an individual. where i work, the monthly backup is secured offsite.

Answer (score 0):

I'd vote for Amazon S3 using the Jungledisk front end.

Dropbox is great, but expensive (it uses S3, but marks up the storage cost). It also seems to have a huge CPU overhead when diff-ing large files.

Jungledisk gives you more control of versioning as well as when and how you want to backup.